# Two different marshallers in spring project

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, marshalling, spring-ws, castor

I need to use two different marshallers typically JaxbMarshaller and CastorMarshaller.
I have spring project with lots of integration modules.

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
    <property name="mappingLocation">
        <value>classpath:config/service/mapping.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
</bean>
```

I also added this to my endpoint to give it JaxbMarshaller but it does not get it

```
public class MyEndPoint extends AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint
```

I need to use both JaxbMarshaller and CastorMarshaller

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately there are two problems that need to be solved:

1. Inject both the JAXB and Castor marshaller/unmarshaller
2. Determine when when to use JAXB or Castor

**Item #1 - Inject both the JAXB and Castor marshaller/unmarshaller**

*org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter* only has one marshaller property and one unmarshaller property.  There may be two ways to solve this problem:

***Option #1 - Subclass GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter***

You could subclass rg.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter and introduce a second marshaller an unmarshaller property.  Then you will configure this something like:

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.example"/>
</bean>
<bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
    <property name="mappingLocation">
        <value>classpath:config/service/mapping.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean
    class="your.domain.YourGenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
    <property name="castorMarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
    <property name="castorMarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
</bean>
```

***Option #2 - Implement Your own Marshaller***

You could implement your own marshaller that is both JAXB and Castor aware.  Then configure it something like:

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="your.domain.CustomMarshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.example"/>
    <property name="mappingLocation">
        <value>classpath:config/service/mapping.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
</bean>
```

**Item #2 - Determine when when to use JAXB or Castor**

This may be the harder item to solve.  Once you have made your endpoint aware of both JAXB and Castor you will still need to choose one to perform the marshal operation.  This aspect may be easier to solve with the custom marshaller approach described above.

**For More Information**

Here are instructions for configuring JAXB with Spring:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Spring/JAXBAnnotations

The following contains instructions for configuring Castor (and JAXB):

- http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/oxm.html

Comment: Thank you for your concern.
But I need to use them both in the same project

Comment: Have you tried combining them in the config?  I have updated my answer to include a fragment of what this might look like.

Comment: I have edited description for this answer
I have made some changes at end point

Comment: Were you able to try the approach I suggested?  You will need to bind the JAXB and Castor marshallers to different properties.

Comment: Actually I didn't. How can i use them now with the existence of GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter. This has nothing to do with webservices. This could be useful if are marshalling objects as you want not with PayLoad EndPoint

Comment: GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter will need separate properties for both JAXB and Castor marshallers.

Comment: Where to to put these? GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter sets marshaller and unmarshaller properties and the are the same one.

Comment: Is it possible to extend org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter so that it will have two marshaller/unmarshaller properties?  What will be your criteria for calling JAXB or Castor?

Comment: I will try this but i don't think it will work cause spring has default marshalling adapter, marshals object before invoking the actual endpoint implementation

Comment: I have updated my answer outlining two possible approaches.  Side question is there a reason you need to support Castor in addition to JAXB?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I used Castor and omitted JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

I ended with a dead end I omitted JAXB, I just use Castor.